# How to extend access token expiration time for MSAL Python library?

Tags: python, datetime, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

When using the MSAL library for Python, I cannot get the access token expiration time to change from the default of 1 hour.

I have tried:

```
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    then = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    
    claims = {
        "exp": then,
    }
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        graph_config["client_id"], authority=graph_config["authority"],
        client_credential=graph_config["secret"], client_claims=claims)
```

I have tried sending this as a python datetime object, and as a string. I have tried adding '_min' to the value, and I have tried the 'now + 10_min' like the docs say.

No matter what, I still get an expiration time of:

```
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "ext_expires_in": 3599,
```

i.e. one hour

Docs: https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#publicclientapplication-and-confidentialclientapplication

Please for the love of all that is holy, someone help me get this stupid access token to last longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token lifetimes are managed by Polices in Azure AD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties so they aren't something that you can change from a user level (but an Admin could alter or create a new policy to do this). The default lifespan is 1 hour for security reasons and unless you have a good reason to change it you shouldn't as its generally easy for any app to manage its own token refresh/renew.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the correct answer, but this has been far easier said then done so far. I (and two co-workers) spent about 3-4 hours yesterday evening trying to get this policy created and applied, and it doesn't seem to take effect. At this point I am lost...